# Save data when Application when and Load data back when application starts again. JAVA FX

Tags: java, javafx, serialization

I have a Java FX program where I have a data model class that holds all model data. In the GUI there are different shapes (corresponding to the data in the data model class). I am trying to figure out a way to save all model data and the shapes in the GUI before application is closed by the user, so when the application starts again I can then load the saved data.

I have tried using Serializable and save the data into a file and then load the data from the file, but I think I might be doing something wrong since it is not working.

My DataModel class that contains observable data (mainly getters and setters):

```
public class DataModel implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ObservableList<UndirectedNonWeightedGraph> undirectedNonWeightedGraphData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ObservableList<UndirectedWeightedGraph> undirectedWeightedGraphData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ObservableList<DirectedNonWeightedGraph> directedNonWeightedGraphData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ObservableList<DirectedWeightedGraph> directedWeightedGraphData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private ObservableList<Vertex<Integer>> vertexDataUndirectedNonWeightedInt = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Vertex<Double>> vertexDataUndirectedNonWeightedDouble = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Vertex<String>> vertexDataUndirectedNonWeightedString = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private ObservableList<Vertex<Integer>> vertexDataUndirectedWeightedInt = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Vertex<Double>> vertexDataUndirectedWeightedDouble = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Vertex<String>> vertexDataUndirectedWeightedString = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private ObservableList<Vertex<Integer>> vertexDataDirectedNonWeightedInt = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Vertex<Double>> vertexDataDirectedNonWeightedDouble = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Vertex<String>> vertexDataDirectedNonWeightedString = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private ObservableList<Vertex<Integer>> vertexDataDirectedWeightedInt = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Vertex<Double>> vertexDataDirectedWeightedDouble = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Vertex<String>> vertexDataDirectedWeightedString = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private UndirectedNonWeightedGraph<Integer> undirectedNonWeightedInt;
private UndirectedNonWeightedGraph<Double> undirectedNonWeightedDouble;
private UndirectedNonWeightedGraph<String> undirectedNonWeightedString;

private UndirectedWeightedGraph<Integer> undirectedWeightedInt;
private UndirectedWeightedGraph<Double> undirectedWeightedDouble;
private UndirectedWeightedGraph<String> undirectedWeightedString;

private DirectedNonWeightedGraph<Integer> directedNonWeightedInt;
private DirectedNonWeightedGraph<Double> directedNonWeightedDouble;
private DirectedNonWeightedGraph<String> directedNonWeightedString;

private DirectedWeightedGraph<Integer> directedWeightedInt;
private DirectedWeightedGraph<Double> directedWeightedDouble;
private DirectedWeightedGraph<String> directedWeightedString;

private ArrayList<Vertex<Integer>> listOfUndirectedNonWeightedIntVertices; 
private ArrayList<Vertex<Double>> listOfUndirectedNonWeightedDoubleVertices; 
private ArrayList<Vertex<String>> listOfUndirectedNonWeightedStringVertices; 

private ArrayList<Vertex<Integer>> listOfUndirectedWeightedIntVertices; 
private ArrayList<Vertex<Double>> listOfUndirectedWeightedDoubleVertices; 
private ArrayList<Vertex<String>> listOfUndirectedWeightedStringVertices; 

private ArrayList<Vertex<Integer>> listOfDirectedNonWeightedIntVertices; 
private ArrayList<Vertex<Double>> listOfDirectedNonWeightedDoubleVertices; 
private ArrayList<Vertex<String>> listOfDirectedNonWeightedStringVertices; 

private ArrayList<Vertex<Integer>> listOfDirectedWeightedIntVertices; 
private ArrayList<Vertex<Double>> listOfDirectedWeightedDoubleVertices; 
private ArrayList<Vertex<String>> listOfDirectedWeightedStringVertices; 

public DataModel() {

    this.undirectedNonWeightedInt = new UndirectedNonWeightedGraph<Integer>();
    this.undirectedNonWeightedDouble = new UndirectedNonWeightedGraph<Double>();
    this.undirectedNonWeightedString = new UndirectedNonWeightedGraph<String>();

    this.undirectedWeightedInt = new UndirectedWeightedGraph<Integer>();
    this.undirectedWeightedDouble = new UndirectedWeightedGraph<Double>();
    this.undirectedWeightedString = new UndirectedWeightedGraph<String>();

    this.directedNonWeightedInt = new DirectedNonWeightedGraph<Integer>();
    this.directedNonWeightedDouble = new DirectedNonWeightedGraph<Double>();
    this.directedNonWeightedString = new DirectedNonWeightedGraph<String>();

    this.directedWeightedInt = new DirectedWeightedGraph<Integer>();
    this.directedWeightedDouble = new DirectedWeightedGraph<Double>();
    this.directedWeightedString = new DirectedWeightedGraph<String>();

    undirectedNonWeightedGraphData.addAll(undirectedNonWeightedInt, undirectedNonWeightedDouble, undirectedNonWeightedString);

    undirectedWeightedGraphData.addAll(undirectedWeightedInt,undirectedWeightedDouble,undirectedWeightedString);

    directedNonWeightedGraphData.addAll(directedNonWeightedInt,directedNonWeightedDouble,directedNonWeightedString);

    directedWeightedGraphData.addAll(directedWeightedInt,directedWeightedDouble,directedWeightedString);

    listOfUndirectedNonWeightedIntVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<Integer>>();
    listOfUndirectedNonWeightedDoubleVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<Double>>();
    listOfUndirectedNonWeightedStringVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<String>>();

    listOfUndirectedWeightedIntVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<Integer>>();
    listOfUndirectedWeightedDoubleVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<Double>>();
    listOfUndirectedWeightedStringVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<String>>();

    listOfDirectedNonWeightedIntVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<Integer>>();
    listOfDirectedNonWeightedDoubleVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<Double>>();
    listOfDirectedNonWeightedStringVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<String>>();

    listOfDirectedWeightedIntVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<Integer>>();
    listOfDirectedWeightedDoubleVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<Double>>();
    listOfDirectedWeightedStringVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<String>>();
}

//REST OF CLASS IS JUST GETTERS AND SETTERS SO WONT INCLUDE

}
```

I created a class ResourceManager that has the save and load methods:

```
public class ResourceManager {

public static void save(Serializable data, String fileName) throws Exception {
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(fileName)))) {
        oos.writeObject(data);
    }
}

public static Object load(String fileName) throws Exception {
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName)))) {
        return ois.readObject();
    }
}
}
```

In my main method I try call the save and load methods accordingly and try to save to a file:

```
public class Main extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;

private DataModel dataModel;
private GraphPanelController controller;

public Main() {

    dataModel = new DataModel();

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Graph Visualiser");

    showGraphPanel();

    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{

        saveData();

    });
}

public void showGraphPanel() {
     try {
            // Load person overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/GraphPanel.fxml"));
            AnchorPane graphPanel = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMain(this);
            controller.setDataModel(dataModel);
            loadData();

            //Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(graphPanel);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public boolean showAddVertexPopUp(GraphPanelController gpc) {
    try {
        // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup dialog.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/AddVertexData.fxml"));
        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // Create the dialog Stage.
        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.setTitle("Add vertex data");
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        dialogStage.setScene(scene);

        // Set the person into the controller.
        AddVertexDataController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
        controller.setGraphPanelController(gpc);
        controller.setMain(this);
        controller.setDataModel(dataModel);

        // Show the dialog and wait until the user closes it
        dialogStage.showAndWait();

        return controller.isOkClicked();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public void saveData() {

    try {
        ResourceManager.save(dataModel, "1.save");
    }catch(Exception e) {

    }


}

public void loadData() {
    try {
        dataModel =  (DataModel) ResourceManager.load("1.save");

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't load save data: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the main stage.
 * @return
 */
public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Any help will be gladly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I recommend looking into the [Java Properties API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) as it makes it very simple to save and load such persistent data.

Comment: I don't think the Java Properties API which inherits from Hashtable is useful. The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Hashtable.html) says: "If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use HashMap in place of Hashtable. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use ConcurrentHashMap in place of Hashtable." I would suggest  saving such data as a file in JSON format.

Comment: Also consider [`java.util.prefs.Preferences`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavafx%5d%20java.util.prefs.Preferences).

Comment: Hey guys thank you for the responses, but I am still a bit confused, I have never come across JSON and do not know how to save the data in a JSON format. Maybe someone can show me a simple example to save shapes and model data when application is closed.